# Valgrind Memory error detection on just call to Py_Initialize() and nothing else

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, valgrind, python-c-api, nist

I am adding my python code into c++ for making an wrapper to c api that can be later used inside cpp as library and everything is working fine but for except one thing that is memory errors.
See bellow code.

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
    Py_Initialize();
    cout <<"Hello\n";
    Py_Finalize();

}
```

While running above code There are no error but when i ran it throigh valgrind for checking of memory leaks then i got so many errors for example

```
==140416== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==140416== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==140416== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==140416== Command: ./test_mem
==140416== Parent PID: 86216
==140416== 
==140416== Invalid read of size 4
==140416==    at 0x4AADA41: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4ACD397: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4ACE9D8: PyDict_SetItem (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x48E2CFE: PyType_Ready (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4AB8E04: _PyTypes_Init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x49F3A6A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x49F41A2: Py_InitializeFromConfig (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x49F424B: Py_InitializeEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x1091ED: main (in /additional_drive/nist/frvt_onnx_sequential/11/test_mem)
==140416==  Address 0x5387020 is 1,520 bytes inside a block of size 2,208 free'd
==140416==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==140416==    by 0x4ACD397: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4AC9E1F: PyDict_SetDefault (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4A62DFF: PyUnicode_InternInPlace (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4A62E90: PyUnicode_InternFromString (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4AFC4C1: PyDescr_NewMethod (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x48E34AA: PyType_Ready (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4AB8E04: _PyTypes_Init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x49F3A6A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x49F41A2: Py_InitializeFromConfig (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x49F424B: Py_InitializeEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x1091ED: main (in /additional_drive/nist/frvt_onnx_sequential/11/test_mem)
==140416==  Block was alloc'd at
...
...
...
==140416==  Block was alloc'd at
==140416==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==140416==    by 0x4AB69E7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4B20CB7: PyGrammar_AddAccelerators (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4B23184: PyParser_New (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4B26DD2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x49E79DA: PyParser_ASTFromStringObject (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x49E8387: PyRun_StringFlags (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4A2BADF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x4ABB546: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x48D0D6C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x48D246C: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416==    by 0x48DC06A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
==140416== 
==140416== ERROR SUMMARY: 898 errors from 107 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

How to manage properly memory errors using python c api
because I want to submit a validation package in a challenge and they have requirement that my program should have memory errors.

I have tried diiferent solutions from internet like

```
setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
```

But that did not fix the problem
When i remove Py_Initialize(); there are no errors and the Valgrind output is cleaned from all errors as well. But I want to run py code inside cpp.

Comment: `Invalid read of size 4` isn't a leak.

Comment: And to see more what is happening you need debug symbols for libpython3.8.so.1.0. Your distro may have debug symbol packages. Otherwise you need to build a debug version of Python.

Comment: @PaulFloyd my concern is 
This line ==> `ERROR SUMMARY: 898 errors from 107 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)`

Comment: Just look at the errors, starting with the first one.